# How to create an object in a form like this: ifstream in();

Tags: c++, definition, function-declaration, ambiguous-grammar

Im beginner in c++. I have seen several times when object created like:

`class_name object_name();`

and after that you can refer to object_name as an object of the class.
How can i do this in my class? Should I override the constructor? And how to do that?

Comment: This creates a function, not an object.

Comment: I think you need to show us a bit more of what you have in mind in order for us to offer an answer or even much in the way of useful commentary.

Comment: Where did you see a variable definition in the form `ifstream in();`?

Comment: You have never seen an object created in that way. I would recommend that you start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Could well be your textbook is too ancient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code can probably trigger a vexing (but not ["the most vexing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)) parse behavior: instead of being interpreted as a variable declaration, it will be interpreted as the declaration of a function named `object_name`, taking no parameters and returning a value of type `class_name`.

See it happen on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3b9nr63cs): The compiler tells you:

```
<source>: In function 'void foo()':
<source>:4:27: warning: empty parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
    4 |     class_name object_name();
      |
```

Comment: @PeteBecker: You're right. This is just a vexing parse.