# In C++, whats the difference between initializing an object with (), {}, or neither of those?

Tags: c++, initialization

In a class, if I have:

```
private:
   MyClass myObj;
```

vs

```
private:
   MyClass myObj();
```

```
private:
   MyClass myObj{};
```

And assuming `MyClass` takes no parameter in its constructor.

Comment: See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

Comment: [The nightmare of initialization in c++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs)  This runs through all the issues in more detail that you can almost stand.

Comment: Brace initialization is immune to the infamous most vexing parse in C++. Also it's recommended in many guidelines over parentheses initialization. It's also safer in some scenarios. However for the types that have constructors with a `std:: initializer_list` as a parameter, it can cause issues. You should be careful in those situations and use parentheses initialization in those cases. One common example is the STL vector.

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this. Moreover, this is explained in any beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Here are some dupes: [dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71806191/how-to-create-an-object-in-a-form-like-this-ifstream-in) and [dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/what-are-the-advantages-of-list-initialization-using-curly-braces)

Answer (score 4):

```
MyClass myObj;
```

This declares a class member named myObj, that gets default-constructed, by default.

```
MyClass myObj();
```

This declares a class method, a class function, named `myObj` that takes no parameters and returns a `MyClass` object.

```
MyClass myObj{};
```

This also declares a class member named myObj, that gets default-constructed, by default, just like without the `{}`.

Welcome to C++.

Comment: With a bunch of asterisks on the first and third one. (Welcome to C++ indeed...)

Comment: The third should be a value-initialization, though, and may end up in a zero-initialization.